# UITableView overlap everything

Tags: swift, xcode

I am a new programmer starting to work with xCode for less than 3 weeks, so the question might seem very stupid to you, but really need your help please..
This question is not duplicate since the similar questions before are regarding overlapping the status bar, but my case is that the navigation bar and tab bar disappear..
Originally I have set up a navigation bar and tab bar in the viewcontroller.
However, after I set up the UITableView by code following the Youtube, it covers everything and the entire page become the table View like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lza6Y.png)

But I was not intend to cover the table to the whole page, but left the navigation bar and table bar appear. And I set up the Viewcontroller like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Qpy7.png)

Could something do a big favor to help me adjust back thank you!
the code is like this:

```
class HomeViewController:UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {

var tableView:UITableView!

var posts = [
Post(id: "1", author: "Donald", text: "Ho"),
Post(id: "2", author: "Brian Yung", text: "Hi")
]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView = UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .plain)
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "PostTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postCell")
    view.addSubview(tableView)

    var layoutGuide:UILayoutGuide!

    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        layoutGuide = view.layoutMarginsGuide
    }
    tableView.contentInset.top = 50
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 32).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.reloadData()


}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! PostTableViewCell
    cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue once too, and could never figure out why it happens, even though seems constraints on view were right... So without any actual solution, I resolved it with the following workaround. See if it helps you as well.

The gist of the workaround is: ***use separate controller for table view, and embed it in "main" view using Container View***

Steps:

1. On a view where you want to add table view, remvoe table view, and add **Container View** where you want table view to be. Create proper constraints for it (should be limited from top and bottom)
2. Create a separate **Table View Controller**. And create a new Controller class for it. All methods from `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` should move from `HomeViewController` to this new controller
3. Create an **Embed** segue from *Container View* to *Table View Controller*
4. Remove `UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource` from `HomeViewController` (it extends `UIViewController` only)

I.e.:

[image]